# Need help to compute derivative and integral using Numpy

Tags: python, methods, difference, integral, derivative

I need help to compute derivative and integral of function using finite difference method and Numpy without using loops.

The whole task: Tabulate Gauss function f(x) = (1./(sqrt(2.*pi)*s))*e**(-0.5*((x-m)/s)**2) on the interval [-10,10] for m = 0 and s=[0.5,5]. Compute derivative and integral of the function using finite difference method without using loops. Create plots of the function and its derivative. Use Numpy and Matplotlib.

Here's the beginning of the programm:

def f(x,s,m):

```
return (1./(sqrt(2.*pi)*s))*e**(-0.5*((x-m)/s)**2)
```

def main():

```
m = 0
s = np.linspace(0.5,5,3)
x = np.linspace(-10,10,20)
for i in range(3):
    print('s = ', s[i])
    for j in range(20):
        f(x[j],s[i],m)
        print('x = ',x[j],', y = ',f(x[j],s[i],m))
```

Comment: You need to add 1 tab to your code to display it properly.

Answer (score 0):

By using the numpy arrays you can apply that operation directly with algebraic notation:

```
result = (1./(np.sqrt(2.*np.pi)*s))*np.exp(-0.5*((x-m)/s)**2)
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way (without using SciPy) seems to me to directly sum for the integral and central difference method for the derivative:

```
import numpy as np
import pylab

def gaussian(x, s, m):
    return 1./(np.sqrt(2.*np.pi)*s) * np.exp(-0.5*((x-m)/s)**2)

m = 0
s = np.linspace(0.5,5,3)
x, dx = np.linspace(-10,10,1000, retstep=True)

x = x[:,np.newaxis]
y = gaussian(x,s,m)

h = 1.e-6
dydx = (gaussian(x+h, s, m) - gaussian(x-h, s, m))/2/h
int_y = np.sum(gaussian(x, s, m), axis=0) * dx
print(int_y)

pylab.plot(x, y)
pylab.plot(x, dydx)
pylab.show()
```